# How to convert date types in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I use only javascript and angularjs framework in my project.

I have date in this format:

```
  var date = "2012-10-04T16:10:00";
```

I convert it:

```
 date = new Date(date);
```

The new value of date:

```
Tue Oct 16 2012 19:10:00 GMT+0300 (Jerusalem Daylight Time)
```

At some point I need to convert it back to this format:

```
"2012-10-04T16:10:00";
```

So my queswtion is how do I make konvertion using javascript from this format :

```
Tue Oct 16 2012 19:10:00 GMT+0300 (Jerusalem Daylight Time)
```

to this:

```
  "2012-10-04T16:10:00";
```

Comment: I believe [`toISOString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) method can do that

Comment: Check out moment.js http://momentjs.com/ for date manipulation, parsing.

Comment: If you are using angular, use angular date filter ; `$filter('date')(date, format, timezone)` Documentation @ https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the
[dateObj.toISOString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString)

Example:

```
var currDate = new Date();
console.log(currDate);
// Tue Apr 12 2016 14:15:42 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
console.log(currDate.toISOString());
// 2016-04-12T08:45:42.794Z
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's the best way to do this. But you can first turn it to a string with String(), then you can edit that strings format either by splitting them into an array like object with Split("The characters you want to split by") or replace certain characters with replace("replace this", "with this");

String function: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_string.asp
Replace function: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp